# Justifying an integration by parts (Evans Chapter 5 Exercise 10)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Integrate by parts to prove 
>   $$\|D u\|_{L^p}\le C \|u\|_{L^p}^\frac{1}{2}\|D^2u\|_{L^p}^\frac{1}{2}$$
>   for $2\le p <\infty$ and all $u\in C^\infty_c(U)$. 
>   (Hint: $\int_U |D u|^pdx=\sum_{i=1}^n \int_U u_{x_i}u_{x_i}|Du|^{p-2}dx$.)

Now, if one mindlessly computes using the hint, integrating by parts, and Hölder's inequality, it is not hard to arrive to the desired result. The problem lies in justifying the integration by parts, because, if $2< p\le 4$, then 
$$ |Du|^{p-2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_i}^2\right)^\frac{p-2}{2}$$
is non-differentiable whenever $Du=0$, since $0<\frac{p-2}{2}\le 1$ (the case $p=2$ should be considered separately). We could try to integrate on $\{Du\neq 0\}$, but we have no information on the geometry of $\partial\{Du\neq 0\}$, i.e. the set need not have a $C^1$ boundary, so the integration by parts formula does not work.

Comment: I suspect you can replace for $p>2$
$$ |v|^p \leftrightarrow N_\epsilon(v) := |v|^2 |v+\epsilon |^{p-2}$$
do your thing, then show convergence as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, you are splitting the terms $u_{x_i}$ and $u_{x_i}|Du|^{p-2}$ apart, so differentiability of $u_{x_i}|Du|^{p-2}$ is all that is required. You can compute the derivative of $u_{x_i}|Du|^{p-2}$ in $x_j$ to be

$$(p-2)|Du|^{p-4} \sum_{i}^n u_{x_i}^2u_{x_ix_j} + u_{x_ix_j}|Du|^{p-2},$$

where $Du\neq 0$. Note this is continuous for $p>2$. At a point $x_0$ where $Du(x_0)=0$ we have $|Du(x_0)|\leq C|x-x_0|$ and so

$$|u_{x_i}(x_0)|Du(x_0)|^{p-2}|\leq C|x-x_0|^{p-1}.$$

Since $p-1>1$ it follows that $u_{x_i}|Du|^{p-2}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and has zero gradient. This shows that $u_{x_i}|Du|^{p-2}$ is continuously differentiable, and integration by parts is justified.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I can see that the derivative is what you've written down when $Du(x)\neq 0$, and that this function is everywhere continuous (the $u^2_{x_i}$ terms in the sum compensate $Du(x)=0$ when taking the limit, right?), but why does that imply the existence of the derivative at the singularities $Du(x)=0$?

Comment: I added some further explanation that should help.