# $W^{2,p}$ estimates for Newtonian potential

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain and let $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ for some $1<p<\infty$. Let 
$$ w(x) = \int_{\Omega} \Gamma(x-y)f(y)dy $$
be the Newtonian potential of $f$, where $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation. By Theorem 9.9 in the book of Gilbarg/Trudinger, we then have $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, $\Delta w=f$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$, moreover $w$ satisfies the estimate 
$$||D^2 w||_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C ||f||_{L^p(\Omega)}.$$
I am interested in the question if $w$ also satisfies an estimate of the form 
$$ ||w||_{W^{2,p}(\Omega)} \leq C ||f||_{L^p(\Omega)}, $$
in particular if the $L^p$ norm of the first order derivatives of $w$ can be controlled by the $L^p$ norm of $f$. If this estimate fails in general, is it satisfied if we assume that $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to find estimates just like that in Gilbarg/Trudinger (dig a little deeper). The first order derivatives can usually be easily controlled with interpolation, once you have control on $D^2w$.

Comment: For example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669714/justifying-an-integration-by-parts-evans-chapter-5-exercise-10/2669896#comment5514849_2669896